# Better understanding of JavaScript closure inside loops

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm dealing with the closure issue right now and I need a little help on the topic:
Using this code for my training:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(j) {
        console.log(j);
    }(i), 1000);
}
```

This solution timeouts for a second and then prints 1-10 in ascending order (as expected).
Now, I want it to print j once every second:

> 1 (second passed...)
>   2 (second passed...)
>   3 (second passed...)
>   etc..

How can I make this happen without changing the formation of the loop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` expects a function to be able to execute. You need to return a function and also, seeing as your `setTimeout` calls will occur one after another, you'll need to delay them

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(j) {
        return function() {
            console.log(j);
        }
    }(i), 1000 * i); // Delay
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmamqvxh/)

That's without changing the formation of the loop. Although your best solution is to not use a for loop, but chain `setTimeout` calls instead:

```
var i = 0;
function start() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        // If we haven't reached our limit, start again
        if(i < 10) start();
    }, 1000);
}
start();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orkfs8fg/)

Comment: I understand there are better ways to solve this, nevertheless Im trying to understand closures so please bear with me...
Ive already tried what you suggested on the first attempt, all it did was to print the result an a whole and then wait for 10 seconds before wrapping up.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MishaShblin Absolutely, so the first way answers your question. The problem isn't really with the closure, which you've created correctly, but the fact that `setTimeout` will only work if it is passed in a function. As it stands you were calling `setTimeout(undefined, 1000)` because your anonymous function never returned a value

Comment: @MishaShblin Didn't see your edit. Check the jsFiddle provided, it should show the code working

Comment: Your problem isn't related to closures at all - calling setTimeout() 10 times in a loop simply won't make them execute "one after another".

Comment: @MishaShblin Nope. Like I said, your *closure* is fine - you have correctly encapsulated the `i` variable and modified it so that it is available at a later stage.. Your usage of `setTimeout` is not. My answer shows the correct your usage of setTimeout, given *your* correct usage of a closure

Comment: RGraham: First, I want to thank you! I think Im starting to understand :)
Could you please explain to me why returning an anonymous function inside the anonymous function solved the problem? I dont understand the difference :-/

Comment: When you call `function(j) { console.log(j); }(i) <--` here you have executed the function. Immediately running it. What you really want, is to have `setTimeout` execute it *for you*. In order to do that, you need to pass it a function as a parameter. Returning a function from your closure, tells `setTimeout` to execute that function once the delay has been hit

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  RGraham for the solution:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)(function (j) {
     setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(j)
     }, 1000*j);
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alongside RGraham's answer, I'd like to point out that when learning javascript, you should try to *avoid* using function expressions - they make code confusing to read.

Here's what your initial code looks like, without a function expression:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(doSomething(i), 1000);
}
function doSomething(i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Or an even clearer representation:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var k = doSomething(i);
    // doSomething doesn't explicitly return anything, so k === undefined
    setTimeout(k, 1000);
}
function doSomething(i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, your problem isn't really related to your closure attempt, but rather the way asynchronous operations work in Javascript. The most commonly used ways to sequence asynchronous operations are the continuation passing style/callbacks and promises.